# How to remove free jqgrid own horizontal scrollbar if autowidth:true is used

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid width is set to occupy at least whole window width using settings from [jqGrid and the autowidth option. How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906300/jqgrid-and-the-autowidth-option-how-does-it-work) answer

```
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
```

Top level toolbar icons are made bigger using style below from answers.

If there are many rows in jqgrid so that vertical scrollbar appears,
those settings cause horizontal scrollbar to appear in Chrome even if all grid columns fit to screen.
How to remove this unnessecary horizontal scrollbar ? It should appear only if sum of column widths is greater that window width.

To reproduce, open page below in chrome so that vertical scrollbar appers.

Horizontal scrollbar appears then also in page but it should not appear.  `<body style="overflow-x:hidden">` cannot used since it disables scrollbar also if it is required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/27617764/315935</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css">
    <style>

        .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; font-weight: normal; }


div > span.ui-pg-button-icon-over-text.fa {
    font-size: 32px;
}

.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-pager .navtable,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-toppager .navtable {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-pg-button-text {
    margin: 4px !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div > span {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.ui-jqgrid td input[type=date], input[type=time], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=month] {
    line-height: normal;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <!--<script src="../jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var mydata = [
                { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },

                { id: "110",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "120",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "130",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "140",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "150",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "160",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "170",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "180",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "190",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "1100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "1110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "1120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },

                { id: "210",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "220",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "230",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "240",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "250",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "260",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "270",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "280",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "290",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "2100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "2110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "2120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }

            ],
            $grid = $("#grid"),
            initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true
                });
            },
            initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initDateEdit(elem);
                }, 100);
            };

        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ["", "Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "act", template: "actions" },
                { name: "name", align: "center", width: 92, editrules: {required: true} },
                { name: "invdate", width: 72, align: "center", sorttype: "date", frozen: true,
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true }, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                { name: "amount", width: 56, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "tax", width: 35, template: "number", autoResizableMinColSize: 40, hidden: true },
                { name: "total", width: 43, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "closed", width: 49, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
                { name: "ship_via", width: 76, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                { name: "note", width: 43, edittype: "textarea", sortable: false }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 100,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,

            rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
            toppager: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            sortorder: "desc",
            navOptions: {
                position: "center",
                addtext: "Add",
                edittext: "Edit",
                deltext: "Delete",
                searchtext: "Search",
                refreshtext: "Reload",
                viewtext: "View",
                savetext: "Save",
                canceltext: "Cancel",
                iconsOverText: true
            },
            caption: "Demonstration how to make full width navigator bar"
        }).jqGrid("navGrid", {view: true})
        .jqGrid("inlineNav")
        //.jqGrid("filterToolbar")
        .jqGrid("gridResize");

        var autoedit = true;
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle",
            id: "AutoEdit",
            title: "Toggle autoedit",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                var $me = $(e.currentTarget);
                $me.toggleClass("ui-state-active");
                autoedit = $me.hasClass("ui-state-active");
                $me.attr("aria-pressed", autoedit ? "true" : "false");
            }
        });

var i;
for (i=0; i<30; i++) {
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle"+i,
            id: "AutoEdit2"+i,
            title: "Toggle autoedit"
        });
}



        $("#grid_toppager")
            .find(".ui-pg-button")
            .each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr({
                    tabindex: String(i),
                    role: "button"
                });
            });
        //$("#AutoEdit").attr("role", "button");
        if (autoedit) {
            $("#AutoEdit").click();
        }
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-table",
            caption: "Columns",
            title: "Choose columns",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager_left").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_center").attr("colspan", "2");
        $("#grid_toppager_center").css({width: "", "text-align": "left", "white-space": ""});
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").append(
            $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">table.ui-pg-table")
        );
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {
            $(this).css("float", "left");
        });
        $grid.bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
            var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $toppager = $(p.toppager);
            $toppager.find(".navtable").css("width", "");
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv" style="margin:5px;">
        <table id="grid"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean probably horizontal *scrollbar* instead of "horizontal toolbar"?

Comment: Thank you. I replaced toolbar with scrollbar in question title and contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the calculation of the width of the grid is not perfect in case of usage of `autowidth: true`. Nevertheless the problem which you describe is not a jqGrid problem. It's good that you included outer div over the grid in the demo which you posted. It shows the complexity of the problem.

First of all it will be displayed no horizontal scroll bar in IE10/IE11 in the demo which you posted. The reason is that IE displays half transparent vertical scrollbar by default. So it's not creates additional horizontal scroll bar in the case which you described.

You can fix the problem by adding the following lines at the end of your demo:

```
if (window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth",
        $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "width") -
        (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}
```

See the results [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/RemovePageHorizontalScrollbar.htm).

On the other side the demo have outer div over the grid with `margin:5px`. If I change the `margin:5px` to `margin:200px` then the same demo will looks as [the following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/RemovePageHorizontalScrollbar1.htm). One can increase the width of the grid to almost 200 additional pixel (the exact maximum is 200 - 4, which I can't explain now, but the value can be changed after I improve the code of `setGridWidth`). See [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/RemovePageHorizontalScrollbar2.htm). The reason: the outer div have both `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to 200px, but the scroll bar *on the page* will not exist if we would ignore the `margin-right`. It's only the margin and there are exist no real elements on the page in the space. Thus the web browsers don't creates horizontal scroll bars in the case.

Comment: I tried this in application where jqgrid is inside bootstrap panel. Problem  persists. if condition if not fulfilled and thus width is not decreased.

Comment: Also, if grid is wider than screen, horizontal toolbar does not appear anymore. I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217324/how-to-show-horizontal-toolbar-in-free-jqgrid-if-autowidth-is-set

Comment: Last demo includes jqgrid two times: `<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Add this style to you code

```
<style type="text/css">
   .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
       overflow-x: hidden !important;
   }
</style>
```