# How to use body horizontal scrollbar in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Jqgrid from github does allow to use browser body element horizontal scrollbar if its properties

```
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
```

are used.

To reproduce, open page below in chrome (created from sample in [How to remove free jqgrid own horizontal scrollbar if autowidth:true is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199868/how-to-remove-horizontal-toolbar-from-free-jqgrid-if-autowidthtrue-and-big-tool) ).

Body element horizontal scrollbar is not usable: it does not allow to scroll into rightmost columns.

How to fix this so that browser body scrollbar can normally used and jqgrid own  horizontal scrollbar does not appear ?

I tried to remove

```
if ( window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
  $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth",
        $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "width") -
        (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}
```

but problem persists.

If grid is wrapped to `<div id="outerDiv" style="margin:5px;">` horizontal scrollbar appears only after grid is resized to minimal width and back to max width. However it does not still allow to scroll to rightmost columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/30199868/315935</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css">
    <style>

        .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; font-weight: normal; }


div > span.ui-pg-button-icon-over-text.fa {
    font-size: 32px;
}

.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-pager .navtable,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-toppager .navtable {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-pg-button-text {
    margin: 4px !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div > span {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.ui-jqgrid td input[type=date], input[type=time], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=month] {
    line-height: normal;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <!--<script src="../jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var mydata = [
                { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },

                { id: "110",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "120",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "130",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "140",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "150",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "160",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "170",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "180",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "190",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "1100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "1110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "1120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },

                { id: "210",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "220",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "230",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "240",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "250",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "260",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "270",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "280",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "290",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "2100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "2110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "2120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }

            ],
            $grid = $("#grid"),
            initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true
                });
            },
            initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initDateEdit(elem);
                }, 100);
            };

        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ["", "Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "act", template: "actions", width: 66 },
                { name: "name", align: "center", width: 92, editrules: {required: true} },
                { name: "invdate", width: 1172, align: "center", sorttype: "date", frozen: true,
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true }, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                { name: "amount", width: 1156, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "tax", width: 1135, template: "number", autoResizableMinColSize: 40, hidden: true },
                { name: "total", width: 1143, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "closed", width: 1149, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
                { name: "ship_via", width: 1176, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                { name: "note", width: 1143, edittype: "textarea", sortable: false }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 100,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,

            rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
            toppager: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            sortorder: "desc",
            navOptions: {
                position: "center",
                addtext: "Add",
                edittext: "Edit",
                deltext: "Delete",
                searchtext: "Search",
                refreshtext: "Reload",
                viewtext: "View",
                savetext: "Save",
                canceltext: "Cancel",
                iconsOverText: true
            },
            caption: "Demonstration how to make full width navigator bar"
        }).jqGrid("navGrid", {view: true})
        .jqGrid("inlineNav")
        //.jqGrid("filterToolbar")
        .jqGrid("gridResize");

        var autoedit = true;
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle",
            id: "AutoEdit",
            title: "Toggle autoedit",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                var $me = $(e.currentTarget);
                $me.toggleClass("ui-state-active");
                autoedit = $me.hasClass("ui-state-active");
                $me.attr("aria-pressed", autoedit ? "true" : "false");
            }
        });

var i;
for (i=0; i<30; i++) {
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle"+i,
            id: "AutoEdit2"+i,
            title: "Toggle autoedit"
        });
}



        $("#grid_toppager")
            .find(".ui-pg-button")
            .each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr({
                    tabindex: String(i),
                    role: "button"
                });
            });
        //$("#AutoEdit").attr("role", "button");
        if (autoedit) {
            $("#AutoEdit").click();
        }
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-table",
            caption: "Columns",
            title: "Choose columns",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager_left").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_center").attr("colspan", "2");
        $("#grid_toppager_center").css({width: "", "text-align": "left", "white-space": ""});
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").append(
            $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">table.ui-pg-table")
        );
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {
            $(this).css("float", "left");
        });

        $grid.bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
            var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $toppager = $(p.toppager);
            $toppager.find(".navtable").css("width", "");
        });

        if (window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
            $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth",
                $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "width") -
                (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth));
        }
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <table id="grid"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the goal of the example. It seems me wrong. You use `shrinkToFit: false`, with `autowidth: true` and with large width of columns. Which sense have such combination of the options? You don't allows to reduce the width of columns (by usage of `shrinkToFit: false`). How you imagine to have no horizontal scrollbar in the jqgrid and on the page? I can't follow you...

Comment: Just remove either `autowidth: true` option or `shrinkToFit: false` option. If you use no outer div the you should add (-4) in the width calculation: `$grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "width") - 4 - (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth));`

Comment: See [the demo1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/scrollbar-Andrus-1.htm) and [the demo2](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/scrollbar-Andrus-2.htm)

Comment: @Oleg: Goal is: jqgrid should use specified column widths. jqgrid own scrollbars should never appear. If jqgrid width is bigger that browser width, browser body element scrollbar should appear and it should used for scrolling

Comment: Then you should **remove `autowidth: true`** like I suggest in my answer and to hold `shrinkToFit: false`.

Comment: @Oleg: yesterdays jqgrid from github causes undefined prompt to appear if inline edit is completed. Code at 2015-04-25 works OK

Comment: @Oleg: using `$grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "width") - 4 - (window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth));` decreases jqgrid width if it is wider than screen. How to run this command only if jqgrid width is less than screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the goal of all options which you use. It seems to me that you need remove `autowidth: true` option. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/scrollbar-Andrus-1.htm).

Comment: if `autowidth:true` is removed and jqgrid width is small, top toolbar buttons wrap to multiple lines. How to set jqgrid min-width to screen width width if autowidth is removed ? Or is there other way to show jqgrid top toolbar in whole screen width ? Or should separate bootstrap toolbar created which invokes jqgrid commands and occupies whole page width always?

Comment: it looks like  removing autowidth and using `var gridWidth = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "width"),
                windowWidth = window.innerWidth - 30;
        if (gridWidth< windowWidth ) {
            $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", windowWidth );
        };` solves the issue. Thank you.